# Removing CRLF at the end of the record(tuple)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I was able to delete `CRLF` in each column in `emp` table using following code:

```
UPDATE emp t
   SET ename = REPLACE(t.ename, '\r\n', '\n')
```

However, another `CRLF` was found at the end of each rows as well.
How could I remove them?

Comment: What do you mean "at the end of each row"?

Comment: When I use select * from emp, I saw ^M characters at the end of the record. For example,      col1 col2 col3 ^M

Comment: I thought it was a trailing character of col3, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all of them like so:

```
UPDATE emp t
   SET ename = REPLACE(REPLACE(t.ename, '\r', ''), '\n', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE emp t
   SET ename = TRIM( TRAILING CHR(13)||CHR(10) FROM t.ename)
```